# What are negative and positive after potentials?

Tags: neurophysiology, action-potential

> **After depolarization:** is the slow repolarization phase which follows a rapid fall in spike potential and extends up to attainment of the RMP level. It is called phase of **negative after potential** and lasts for about 4 ms.
>
> After reaching the resting level (–70 mV) the potential further falls and becomes more negative (–72 mV).This phase is called **after hyperpolarization** or phase of positive after potential.

What is the reason for naming them as negative and positive after potentials?

My attempt: I think we are naming them based on the direction
of current, i.e. during after depolarisation membrane potential is going further negative , so the name negative after potential, and during after hyper polarisation, membrane potential is going from hyper polarised state to resting state, so its named as positive after potential.

Am I correct?

---

Source:[Textbook of physiology](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RZcXAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=After%20depolarization%20is%20the%20slow%20repolarization%20phase%20which%20follows%20a%20rapid%20fall%20in%20spike%20potential%20and%20extends%20up%20to%20attainment%20of%20the%20RMP%20level.%20It%20is%20called%20phase%20of%20negative%20after%20potential%20and%20lasts%20for%20about%204%20ms.&source=bl&ots=tfxZXvhxsP&sig=J8CJPe_Cev5L0CLvjUvTi64WMfI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ47T0iZLVAhVBNpQKHcblAPsQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=After%20depolarization%20is%20the%20slow%20repolarization%20phase%20which%20follows%20a%20rapid%20fall%20in%20spike%20potential%20and%20extends%20up%20to%20attainment%20of%20the%20RMP%20level.%20It%20is%20called%20phase%20of%20negative%20after%20potential%20and%20lasts%20for%20about%204%20ms.&f=false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The negative current is hyperpolarising the axon and the positive current is returning it to baseline from a hyperpolarised state.

They are often referred to as inward/outward (negative/positive respectively) currents as well, due to the direction of the flow of ions. Which is further compounded when you start looking positive/negative ions.

Inward currents are inflow of +ve charge, or outflow of -ve charge.
[Outward currents are vice-versa.](http://www.unm.edu/~toolson/voltage_clamp_results_web_page.htm)

Comment: One doubt: we can see that during After hyperpolarization phase only last half of curve is having positive slope ( so positive current) then what about initial half in which curve is having negative slope( so negative current).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, from your source, the trace drops to about -72mV immediately before point E. The bit from where it crosses -70 to E is the negative after potential.

Comment: Ah! got it, I was just confused by the Fig2.1-12 on pg52. Thanks.